# Table not being created in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0.9

I am using Grails 3.0.9

**application.yml:**

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: root
    password: 123

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blereview?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

on `grails run-app` no errors on console but no table is created in the database. 
Domain class I am using

```
DataRequest { 
String token;
 static constraints = { }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have any domain class in your application?

Comment: Shashank I just added my domain in question .

Comment: Why do you have empty `dataSource:` option in config? I would also recommend using `create-drop` instead of `update` and initializing database rows in bootstrap. Hibernate will fail to update schema in case of bigger changes to domains

Comment: I am using a dummy with one domain , but same result . I am using Java 7, Grails 3.0.9 , mysql 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows,one of my friend is also facing same issue.He fixed it by setting GRAILS-HOME using cygwin(grails run-app from cygwin) and it works for him.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: It works . Still I am not able to find issues. I switched to 3.1.* it is working fine with all IDEs